# Username in home directory path

Tags: linux, user-accounts, home-directory

I have a requirement to create new user home directories in a sub-directory of the username in a different base directory to the norm.  The required location is `/users/{user}/home`. Currently, when a new user is created, it is manually moved from the default to the required directory.

I can change the base directory in `/etc/default/useradd`, but here you are unable to specify `{user}` as a variable.  The man page for changing the defaults of useradd states

```
The user's name will be affixed to the end of BASE_DIR to form the new user's home directory name ...
```

- Is it possible to do this with the `useradd` file, perhaps some hidden trick?
- Is this "acceptable"? (ie should I force a change to an established system to bring it in line with standards?)

*(I am aware I can put some commands into `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` to move the home directory after creation.  Is this the only/proper way to do this?)*

Comment: What tool are you using to create the accounts? Could you use a different tool?

Comment: How about `-d`? I think one can create a wrapper `useradd` command that takes `LOGIN` from its last positional parameter, prepares an option-argument for `-d` and calls the real `useradd`. This is not an answer because I'm not answering any of your explicit questions.

Comment: The accounts are created via webmin, so can put in the path as anything I want, but relies on the user remembering and changing it - I was looking for something a little more automatic, but don't think thats possible without writing some script(s)